# Heroku Host Issue

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

I'm trying to host a Discord Bot with a free dyno of Heroku, for some reason I'm getting this problem.

```
2020-07-28T07:37:50.141832+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node src/link_bot.js`
2020-07-28T07:37:50.802589+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-07-28T07:37:50.815799+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Idling
2020-07-28T07:37:50.819227+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to down
2020-07-28T07:37:50.827486+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Idling because quota is exhausted
2020-07-28T07:37:57.010586+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error waiting for network: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Why is this happening? What can I do?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h82-free-dyno-quota-exhausted here the error is explained, in a few words, you need to start paying heroku to be able to make this work

Answer (score 1):

Dyno free hours are over. You have to wait until another month, then they will renew.